# Extracting Gif Files and putting them in a folder within the contents of the app

Tags: applescript

The AppleScript I'm making extracts the frames from a gif file and puts the individual images in a folder inside the application's contents. It then changes the desktop background rapidly to the images inside the folder, hence giving you a gif for a wallpaper. However, I can't figure out how to extract the gif files to the folder in the application. This is what I have so far:

```
on delay duration
set endTime to (current date) + duration
repeat while (current date) is less than endTime
    tell AppleScript to delay duration
end repeat
end delay
set gifFiles to choose file of type "com.compuserve.gif" with prompt "Select  GIF"
tell application "System Events" to set gifFileName to name of gifFiles
set dest to quoted form of POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents:Resources:Gif"

set pScript to quoted form of "from AppKit import NSApplication, NSImage, NSImageCurrentFrame, NSGIFFileType; import sys, os
tName=os.path.basename(sys.argv[1])
dir=sys.argv[2]
app=NSApplication.sharedApplication() 
img=NSImage.alloc().initWithContentsOfFile_(sys.argv[1])
if img:
     gifRep=img.representations()[0]
 frames=gifRep.valueForProperty_('NSImageFrameCount')
 if frames:
     for i in range(frames.intValue()):
         gifRep.setProperty_withValue_(NSImageCurrentFrame, i)
         gifRep.representationUsingType_properties_(NSGIFFileType, None).writeToFile_atomically_(dir + tName + ' ' + str(i + 1).zfill(2) + '.gif', True)
     print (i + 1)"

repeat with f in gifFiles
set numberOfExtractedGIFs to (do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c " & pScript & " " & (quoted form of POSIX path of f) & " " & dest) as integer
end repeat
repeat
try
    set desktop_image to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif:" & gifFileName & " 01.gif"
    tell application "Finder" to set the desktop picture to desktop_image
end try
delay 0.05
try
    set desktop_image to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif:" & gifFileName & " 02.gif"
    tell application "Finder" to set the desktop picture to desktop_image
end try
delay 0.05
try
    set desktop_image to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif:" & gifFileName & " 03.gif"
    tell application "Finder" to set the desktop picture to desktop_image
end try
delay 0.05
try
    set desktop_image to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif:" & gifFileName & " 04.gif"
    tell application "Finder" to set the desktop picture to desktop_image
end try
delay 0.05
try
    set desktop_image to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif:" & gifFileName & " 05.gif"
    tell application "Finder" to set the desktop picture to desktop_image
end try
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in the script.

- `choose file` returns a single file. The repeat loop `repeat with f in gifFiles` breaks the script.
- The proper POSIX path to the destination folder is
  `set dest to quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/Resources/Gif")`
- A slash must be added when composing the file path

Try this, the script assumes that the folder `Gif` in the `Resources` folder exists.

```
set gifFile to choose file of type "com.compuserve.gif" with prompt "Select  GIF"
tell application "System Events" to set gifFileName to name of gifFile
set dest to quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/Resources/Gif")

set pScript to quoted form of "from AppKit import NSApplication, NSImage, NSImageCurrentFrame, NSGIFFileType; import sys, os
tName=os.path.basename(sys.argv[1])
dir=sys.argv[2]
app=NSApplication.sharedApplication() 
img=NSImage.alloc().initWithContentsOfFile_(sys.argv[1])
if img:
 gifRep=img.representations()[0]
 frames=gifRep.valueForProperty_('NSImageFrameCount')
 if frames:
  for i in range(frames.intValue()):
   gifRep.setProperty_withValue_(NSImageCurrentFrame, i)
   gifRep.representationUsingType_properties_(NSGIFFileType, None).writeToFile_atomically_(dir + '/' + tName + ' ' + str(i + 1).zfill(2) + '.gif', True)
  print (i + 1)"


do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c " & pScript & " " & (quoted form of POSIX path of gifFile) & " " & dest
tell application "Finder"
    set extractedGiFFiles to files of folder ((path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:Gif:")
    repeat
        repeat with aFile in extractedGiFFiles
            set the desktop picture to aFile
            delay 0.05
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```